# Keep labels at fixed distance when shrinking graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am visualizing survey data and comparing responses from black vs. white students. I created a function to create dumbbell plots.

```
dumbbell = function(df) {
  ggplot(df, aes(pct_responses, Domain)) +
    geom_line(aes(group=Domain)) +
    geom_point(aes(color=race), size=5) +
    vertical_theme + #custom theme that I made
    scale_color_manual(labels = c("Black Students", "White Students"), 
                       values=c("#073b47", "#e59918")) +
    scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), 
                       limits=c(0,100), 
                       breaks = seq(0, 100, by=20),
                       labels = function(x) paste0(x,"%")) +
    labs(x = "% of Affirmative Responses") +
    scale_y_discrete(labels = wrap_format(40)) +
    geom_text_repel(aes(label=paste0(round(pct_responses),"%")), size=3.52778, family="Georgia", nudge_y=0.3, nudge_x=1.6, segment.color=NA)
}
```

Even though I put in nudge_y to keep the labels at a fixed distance from the colored circles, when I save graphs as different sizes, the space between the label and the circle changes. See for example below:

```
dumbbell(df)
ggsave("test1.png", w=6.5, h=3, unit="in")
ggsave("test2.png", w=6.5, h=3.6, unit="in")
```

[image: image saved at 3 inches in height]

[image: image saved at 3.6 inches in height]

How do I keep the distance fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nudge_y=0.3` will move the labels by 0.3 units (where the implicit distance between each y label is 1 unit). But 0.3 units along an axis will be a greater physical distance when the plot is rendered with a larger physical size. You could try to calculate the nudge amount as some fraction of the rendered height of the plot, but it's probably easier to just use `vjust`, which will keep the labels near the dumbbells. Here's an example (data adapted from [here](https://rpubs.com/ageek/ggplot-adv-part2)):

```
library(tidyverse)

health <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/selva86/datasets/master/health.csv")
health$Area <- factor(health$Area, levels=as.character(health$Area))

dat = health %>% 
  slice(1:3) %>% 
  gather(key, value, -Area)

ggplot(dat, aes(value, Area)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=Area)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=key), size=5) +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(round(value*100),"%")), size=3.52778, 
            family="Georgia", vjust=-1.5) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0.2,0)) +
  theme_classic()

ggsave("test1.png", w=6.5, h=3, unit="in")
ggsave("test2.png", w=6.5, h=4, unit="in")
```

[image]
[image]

Another, possibly cleaner, option is to plot the numbers right on the dumbells:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(value, Area)) +
  geom_line(aes(group=Area)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=key), size=9) +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste0(round(value*100, 1),"%")), size=3.5, 
            family="Georgia", colour="white") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to specify a different unit for nudge_y/nudge_x, such as points/pixels/inches?

Comment: AFAIK, you can only specify distances for `nudge_*` in axis units.